# Using onSizeChanged in Drawable class

Tags: java, android, android-drawable

I have created a custom class which extends `Drawable`. I'm trying to get the dimensions of the Drawable by using `onSizeChanged()` as follow

```
public class Circle extends Drawable {
    ...
    @Override
    protected void onSizeChanged(int xNew, int yNew, int xOld, int yOld) {
        super.onSizeChanged(xNew, yNew, xOld, yOld);
    }
}
```

But I'm getting an error saying that "Method does not override from the superclass". What do I do to fix it?

---

Thanks a lot to [Michael Spitsin](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4052962/michael-spitsin) for this answer. To get the dimensions of the layout which the drawable is attached to, use the following code

```
@Override
protected void onBoundsChange(Rect bounds) {
    mHeight = bounds.height();
    mWidth = bounds.width();
}
```

Comment: There is no such method in Drawable class.

Comment: Could you please explain, what do you want to achieve?

Comment: I want to get the length and width of the view which the drawable is attached to

Comment: Why? What do you want to achieve? Could you please, explain more?

Comment: In drawable there is callback `onBoundsChanged` it calls when view changes drawable sizes.

Comment: Let me test onBoundsChanged. In the activity, I'm attaching the drawable to a relative layout like this `layout.setBackground(new Circle());` I want the dimensions of relative layout

Comment: Yes it worked. Thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If we go to View [source code](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/2.0_r1/android/view/View.java) and in Drawable [source code](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/5.1.1_r1/android/graphics/drawable/Drawable.java#Drawable), we will see next things:

In View.setBackgroundDrawable(Drawable) if we pass not null, than field `mBackground` (is is responsible to store background drawable) is updated.

If we will try to find usages of method `Drawable.onBoundsChanged()` then we will see that it is mainly used in `Drawable.setBounds` method. And if we will find usages of it, we will see next snippet in View.class:

```
private void drawBackground(Canvas canvas) {
    final Drawable background = mBackground;
    if (background == null) {
        return;
    }

    if (mBackgroundSizeChanged) {
        background.setBounds(0, 0,  mRight - mLeft, mBottom - mTop);
        mBackgroundSizeChanged = false;
       rebuildOutline();
    }

    //draw background through background.draw(canvas)
}
```

Thus, using of `onBoundsChanged` callback is accepted for your task.